# Whirlpool washing machine won't start, need help replacing fuse

Tags: circuit-breaker, washing-machine

My Whirlpool washing machine died today. The control panel lights are unresponsive, so it looks like there's a problem with its electricals. The socket works, and the troubleshooting manual mentions the fuse.

I've removed the top panel of the machine. Is there an electrical fuse here somewhere?

**The washer is a Whirlpool AA600 AWO/R5040**

I've had great difficulty finding technical manuals for this washer so I'm sorry for posting a trivial question.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I found one version that has the fuse in the cord cap (at the prongs under a cover). It was a UK style plug, not the U.S. style. What is your location in the world?

Unplug and look between the prongs. There should be a small access door/plastic cover for the fuse. I did find a [manual download link](http://preview.u-manual.com/preview-manual-for-free-32969/washing-machine-whirlpool-awo-r-5040/page-1.html#). Check the last page for the pic of the plug/fuse.

Comment: Greece, EU. Should be pretty similar.